# Шикарный баг в PHP :)

Tags: php

```
    <?php
Class A {
        protected $a = 'Если ты меня видишь, я - баг :)';
}

Class B extends A {
        public function getA () {
                $a = new A();
                echo $a->a;
        }
}

$b = new B();
echo $b->getA();
?>
```

Как-то так :) Будьте осторожны, товарищи :)

Comment: В чём собственно Баг? В protected?

Comment: Ну как-бы да :)

Comment: Как бы, у B есть доступ к protected функциям, ибо наследник, область видимости и все такое.

Comment: Вам бы заголовки в желтую прессу писать...

Comment: Ну это неправильно !! :D Какого черта я получаю доступ к области видимости стороннего объекта ? :))) Он то сторонний :)) Если бы я выполнил просто $this->a - тогда нормально, но я специально создал отдельный объект :)) Попробуйте в любом дрвгом норм языке такое провернуть ))) Это дырень-дырень :) ... Фактически - пропадает особенность protected переменных

Comment: Напомнило [**вот это**][1].

[1]: http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20090830.gif

Comment: Станислав, вы гениальный разработчик - нашли такой баг, а ведь прошло столько лет! И надо же - никто не заметил этого бага.

Ребят, как на такой тупой троллинг можно повестись вообще? Кто-нибудь грамотный, удалите вопрос.
Вам реально заголовки в газетах писать.

Comment: @Kremchik  :)

Человек просто путает private и protected в php.

Comment: ПС надо исправить вопрос на "Шикарный баг в ООП :)" :)

Comment: Ага, а рефлексия, в таком случае - так вообще один супербаг, там вообще можно к private свойствам получить доступ! :) 

    class A { private $a = '1'; }
    $a = new A();
    $p = new ReflectionProperty("A", "a");
    $p->setAccessible(true); 
    var_dump($p->getValue($a));

Пардон, avp тоже самое ниже написал уже :)

Comment: Минуснул за ругательство на PHP :)

Comment: @Rules, жаль что комменты нельзя минусовать =)

Comment: @Asen как давно мне этого не хватает :DDD

Comment: Кто плюсы то вопросу ставит?

Comment: Бред. Это не баг и не фича, а кривые руки прогера :)

Comment: @Construct да кто кто, те кто мой ответ минусуют те и вопросу плюсики ставят :)

Comment: @Kremchik на самом деле тут всё правильно, такое же поведение в Java. И только C++ с этим не согласен. Так что переименовывать в "Шикарный Баг ООП" излишне. @Ilya Pirogov рефлексии были созданы, чтобы получать информацию о классах, функциях и т.д, поэтому было бы бессмысленно если бы они не могли получать доступ к защищенным членам.

Comment: Квартиру мы запрём, чтобы воры не забрались. А чтобы при нужде открыть можно было, на гвоздик рядышком отмычку повесим. Главное, чтобы до ключа никто не добрался.

Comment: @activist, я знаю, я даже это писал как комментарий к ответу, который человек удалил сразу после того, как я это написал. Ну я стебанул с переименованием. Я к тому, что вопрос реально заголовок тролльной прессы напоминает. Тут в принципе бага нет. Я понимаю, человек бы задал вопрос "почему вот так", а тут "Будьте осторожны, товарищи :)" - маразматично как-то это.
<br />
На стеке под такого рода вопросами обычно пишут "and the question is?.."

Comment: Печально что про область видимости и память люди до сих пор не знают и сливают себе карму такими глупыми вопросами, хотя если заскринить и на пикабу школоте показать чтобы поржали

Answer (score 30):

- **Это не баг, а фича.**

> Но интересно, что точного ответа на вопрос *"Почему так?"* никто не дал *(а я два раза пытался, но отвечал неправильно, пришлось даже немного помучать [Eric Lippert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/) :)* Вообще, крутой вопрос, поскольку у людей, программирующих, скажем, на Java / C#, такие языковые решения могут вызывать определенные вопросы.

- Итак, сравниваем поведение PHP и C# в плане спецификаторов области видимости. Оба языка разграничивают видимость, используя *per class* подход, то есть, любой объекта класса `MyClass` может обращаться к любым `private` полям **любого объекта** `MyClass`.

  ---

  ```
   Class A {
       private $a = 'Howdy!';
   }

   Class B extends A {
       public function howdy() {
           $created = new A();
           echo $created->a;
       }
   }

   $b = new B();
   echo $b->howdy();  <--------- Нет fatal'a, поскольку этот код валиден.
  ```

  ---
- Поскольку в PHP система типов динамическая, то проверки доступа возникают в рантайме, а не *(как, скажем в C#)* на этапе компиляции. *Именно этим фактом и обусловлена разница в поведении языков при разграничении видимости `protected` членов класса.*
- Если заменить в написанном коде `private` на `protected`, то в PHP это тоже будет валидный код и это поведение специфицировано [**здесь.**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php) Намного более интересный вопрос - **почему так нельзя сделать, скажем, в C#?**
- *Рассмотрим следующий пример:*

  ---

  ```
   public class Fox
   {
       protected string FurColor;
       private string furType;

       public void PaintFox(Fox anotherFox)
       {
           anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
           anotherFox.furType = "Hey!";
       }
   }

   public class RedFox : Fox
   {
       public void IncorrectPaintFox(Fox anotherFox)
       {
           // Это - ошибка компиляции! ('FurColor' is inaccessible).
           anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
       }

       public void CorrectPaintFox(RedFox anotherFox)
       {
           // А это - валидный код.
           anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
       }
   }
  ```

  ---
- Для C# тоже есть [**спецификация**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979), которая разрешает в таких случаях видимость для `private`, но запрещает `protected` видимость при оперировании другими классами из этой же иерархии. Причина очень простая - поскольку система типов статическая, то проверка области видимости должна осуществляться на этапе компиляции, что невозможно, например, в следующем случае:

  ---

  ```
   public void IncorrectPaintFox(Fox anotherFox)
   {
       anotherFox = new BlueFox();

       // Непонятно, как статически осуществить проверку доступности этого поля.
       anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
   }
  ```

  ---
- В PHP же это возможно благодаря тому, что visibility проверки осуществляются уже в рантайме. Идеологически такое решение позволяет, например, писать следующие вещи:

  ---

  ```
   class Int {
       protected $value = 0;

       public function __construct($value) {
           $this->value = (int) $value;
       }
       public function add(Int $new) {
           return new Int($new->value + $this->value);
       }
   }

   $a = new Int(1);
   $b = new Int(2);
   $c = $a->add($b);
  ```

  ---
- В общем-то, не мне судить о *"верности"* того или иного подхода, но было достаточно интересно докопаться до истины и понять, чем были обусловлены данные языковые решения.
- Рекомендую к прочтению [**пост Эрика Липперта**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/491031.aspx) на данную тему с точки зрения C#.
- Забавно, что в PHP 5.1.x реальная реализация не соответствовала спецификации и это было исправлено только в PHP 5.2.x. См. [**#Bug37632**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37632) и [**#Bug37212.**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37212)

Comment: я бы не назвал это багом или фичей в принципе, он работает так как задумано разработчиками, и не более того.

Comment: Отличное резюме. 

В очередной раз укрепился в еретическом убеждении, что ограничение видимости полей/методов класса (структуры) при доступе к экземпляру по ссылке (адресу) вносит дополнительные проблемы (разгадывание чужих головоломок) в практику программирования.

Comment: Чегой-то я не понял. Что, есть разница в видимости (на примере C++) для a.b и (&a)->b ?

Comment: @alexlz Если `->` не перегружен, то, разумеется, нет.

Comment: @Котик Так я и хотел понять, где оно, "ограничение видимости полей/методов класса (структуры) при доступе к экземпляру по ссылке (адресу)"

Comment: Фича - это когда программа одновременно работает и правильно и неправильно.

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/directly-access-private-in-other-instances.html

Answer (score 18):

И что?

ты вызываешь функцию **$b->getA();** которая берет данные из

```
 Class A {
            protected $a = 'Если ты меня видишь, я - баг :)';
    }
```

Которая наследует, где баг то?
Ты же не выводишь просто **$a** которая protected

вот тебе [ссылка](http://www.php.su/learnphp/phpoo/?php5) для примера

проще говоря, `$b->getA();` наследуется и имеет доступ к переменной protected! вызови её из другого класса и не прокатит. Все логично.

> A note about private members, the doc says "Private limits visibility
>   only to the class that defines the item" this says that the following
>   code works as espected:

```
<?php
class A {
    private $_myPrivate="private";

    public function showPrivate()
    {
        echo $this->_myPrivate."\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function show()
    {
        $this->showPrivate();
    }
}

$obj=new B();
$obj->show(); // shows "private\n";
?>
```

> this works cause A::showPrivate() is defined in the same class as
>   $_myPrivate and has access to it.

**Protected виден классам-наследникам, а private нет. Что вы до сих пор это не понимаете?**

**Protected** (защищённый): Защищённые методы или переменные доступны только внутри класса, где они были объявлены **и из его производных классов.**

А вот

**Private** (закрытый): Закрытые методы или переменные **доступны только внутри класса**.

Вот это

```
Class B extends A {
        public function getA () {
                $a = new A();
                echo $a->a;
        }
```

и вот это

```
class B extends A {
        public function show()
        {
            $this->showPrivate();
        }
    }

    $obj=new B();
    $obj->show();
```

Одно и тоже, какая нафиг разница, где вы этот экземпляр сделаете, в расширенном классе B или после описания всего класса. Результат будет один и тот же. Не вижу здесь бага.

Comment: Не из класса, а из экземпляра класса :)
При вызове он должен учитывать только пространство в созданном объекте, а пространство объекта в коном он был создан - не наследуется (точнее - не должно) )

Comment: >пространство объекта в коном он был создан - не наследуется (точнее >- не должно) )

так убери 

**Class B extends A {**  и твой *БАГ* исчезнет

Comment: @shrek вашим ООП скиллам -1, баг есть - это факт

Comment: PHP обнаглел. А вот при Сталине такого бы не случилось.

Comment: @shrek Ваши примеры описывают отношения в иеарархии, а тут отношения между экземплярами, и один экземпляр класса не должен видеть защищенные свойства другого.
@Станислав советую написать bugreport разработчикам Zend Engine.

Comment: Просто разработчики понимают, что для практики **protected** лишняя сущность.

Comment: >один экземпляр класса не должен видеть защищенные свойства другого

А ***какого*** простите вы его тогда вызываете в расширенном классе первого? Вызывайте его в другом месте!

Comment: Шрек - в универ, учи ООП :) А еще лучше - поучи Java, либо C++, либо C# :) Как тебя приштырит, когда экзепшн вылетит :))

Comment: @shrek ну это уже вопрос эстетики. Если я сделал свойство защищенным, значит мне так надо, и я хочу видеть ошибку при обращении к нему. И меня не должно волновать откуда я работаю со свойствами. Я точно должен быть уверен, что свойство изменяет только мой экземпляр класса.

Comment: @Станислав Комар, ну, в Java через рефлексию даже private доступны.

Потом, разве ООП во всех языках одинаковое ? ООП это некая концепция (любимая *боьшими учеными*), реализуемая в разных языках немного по разному.

Comment: @Станислав Комар
>Шрек - в универ, учи ООП 

да ладно не знал.

@avp написал правильно что

> ООП это некая концепция (любимая боьшими учеными), реализуемая в разных языках немного по разному.

Comment: @avp А "любимая боьшими учеными" -- это кем? Может всё-таки "британскими учёными"?

Comment: php.net/protected

Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is because the implementation specific details are already known when inside those objects.

Как говорится, хорошо задокументированный баг - автоматически становится фичей!

Comment: @activist ну и что нашли вы свой баг или это просто глупый вопрос?

>вашим ООП скиллам -1, баг есть - это факт

где баг-то? Учи матчасть и читай мануалы, говорят помогает :)

Comment: @Shrek как раз таки это не классический случай, а вы пытались доказать обратное.

Comment: @alexlz, нет, **не британскими учеными**, точно. 

*Большими учеными*  называли людей, котрые в академических НИИ, ВУЗах и т.п. обожали писать разные статьи, обобщающие *передовой опыт*.

Comment: @Shrek а я с Вами согласен и  у меня точно такой же код на Java выдал точно такой же баг. Либо я реально уже туплю, либо действительно бага нет

Comment: @erofeev
> Ваши примеры описывают отношения в иеарархии, а тут отношения 
> между экземплярами, и один экземпляр класса не должен видеть 
> защищенные свойства другого. 

То есть например в Java в методе equals(A other) не должно быть доступа к полю a у other (по вашей логике)? 

(естественно я имею в виду Object other  с дальнейшим приведением.)

Answer (score 0):

Protected (защищённый): Защищённые **методы или переменные доступны только внутри класса**, где они были объявлены и из его производных классов.

Comment: Ну производный здесь - B. Но в нем то экземпляр A. А я напрямую из A вызываю протектедную переменную :))) А-а--а-аа-а-а-а !!!! Жесть жестокая :)

Comment: @Станислав Комар вообще мне тоже кажется, что между 

    function B() {
      $a = new A();
      echo $a->a;
    } 

и

    class C extends A {
      function getA() {
        $a = new A();
        echo $a->a;
      }
    }

разницы быть не должно, ибо это просто *другое* пространство. А пэхапе тут со мной не согласен и это грустно)

Хорошо, что php для меня не был первым языком))

Comment: @Sh4dow А Вы первый вариант на java напишите...

Comment: @alexlz, не работаю с явой, но если она на этом месте упадет, то я это и имел в виду)

Comment: @alexlz и что должно быть? точно такое же поведение. И я не удивлен

Comment: @rasmisha Извините, я не знал, что в java можно объявить функцию вне   класса. Можно код посмотреть?

Comment: @alexlz в main сделал то что тут вне класса

Comment: Моя не понимай. Нельзя ли код глянуть?

Comment: Ну как то так (как в комментах выделять код?)

    public class A {
         protected String a = "bug";
    }

    public class B extends A {
     public String getA() {
     A a = new A();
     return a.a;
    }

   }

   public class TestBug { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     B b = new B();
     System.out.println(b.getA());
    }
    }

Comment: @Sh4dow, однако это поведение нельзя называть багом, только потому, что вам или еще кому-либо не нравится идеология PHP. Это задокументированное и предопределенное разработчиками PHP поведение и по этому не является багом.

Для примера, в питоне вообще можно получить доступ практически ко всему, вплоть до декларации класса. Но это не значит, что питон весь напичкан "шикарными багами". Просто это такая идеология языка, она не обязана следовать каким-либо шаблонам или чьим-либо мнениям.

Comment: @rasmisha Спасибо, продолжать не надо. Мы на разных языках говорим мало-мало. Я имел в виду функции в традиционном смысле, без классов, чего в java вроде быть не может. Посмотрел код -- слова class есть. Ну и ладно. Я не так понял и дальше углубляться не стоит.

Comment: @alexlz, комментариями выше просто приведён код, копирующий код из вопроса 1 в 1 без оговорок. Тут и углубляться-то некуда кроме того, что оригинальный вопрос распространяется и на Java тоже.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, я не против, когда недоступные переменные получаются специальными средствами, т.к. это означает, что программер хотя бы примерно понимает, что он делает. Но в данном случае я скорее признаю одним большим багом идеологию PHP (впрочем, я и так давно близок к этому))

Хотя я не буду спорить с тем, что для php в большинстве случаев public+static+private поуши достаточно и потому на этот protected просто не обращаю внимания)

Comment: Да, заголовок "PHP - это баг" был бы более уместен :)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov "PHP - это баг" мило звучит :)

Answer (score 0):

Простая проверка:

```
<?php
Class A {
        protected $a = 'Если ты меня видишь, я - баг :)';
}

Class B extends A {
    function setA(){
        $this->a = 'new type of BUG';
    }
        public function getA () {
                $a = new A();
                echo $a->a;
        }
}

$b = new B();
$b->setA();
echo $b->getA();
?>
```

Ой, что-то не оттуда А берется. А все почему? А потому что строкой `$a = new A();` вы создаете новый объект, с не приватной а, и потом используете новый объект.

Answer (score 0):

Хозяин который писал этот код не понимает основы php.

```
<?php
    Class A {
           protected $a = 'Если ты меня видишь, ';
    }

    Class B extends A {
           public function getA(){
                 $a = 'TTTT'; //ЛОКАЛЬНАЯ
                 $this->a = $this->a.'ТО ЭТО PROTECTED'; //ВАШ PROTECTED
                 echo $this->a;
           }
    }

    $b = new B();
    $b->getA();
?>
```

Comment: вы, кажется, не заметили отсутствия использования this в вопросе. автор удивлен тем, что у него есть доступ к другому объекту, хотя ООП как раз-таки определяет видимость внутри класса, а не конкретного объекта.